# ruby pack unpack question

Tags: ruby

```
> [65].pack('c')
 => "A"
```

In the above case `65` is stored as `1000 0010`. Since `c` returns `8-bit unsigned char` the returned value is `65` which happens to be the ASCII code for `A`.

I do not get the result of following two operations. Any explanations would help.

```
> ['A'].pack('H')
 => "\xA0" 
> ['A'].pack('h')
 => "\n"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the documentation you find this:

```
H         | String  | hex string (high nibble first)
h         | String  | hex string (low nibble first)
```

I don't know why you'd need to flip nibbles, but the facility is there if you need it.

In your case `A` is being interpreted as `A0` one way, and `0A` in the other. Hex input should be provided as character pairs.

Comment: Do you mean to suggest that 0A is same as "\n"

Comment: I think the first nibble in 'h' case is '1000' which translates to 8 in decimal and the ascii value of 8 is backspace. So that explains the backspace. the second nibble is '0001' which has decimal value of 1 and the ascii value for 1 is 'start of heading' which might be represented as 'n'. So that explains '\n' for 'h'.

Comment: Since 'H' looks at nibble so for value '1000001' the first nibble will be '1000' and second one will be '0001'. Since none of those values translate to 'A' so now I am confused by why the result of 'H' has value 'A' and zero.

Comment: `"\n"` is actually the representation for ASCII character 10, or in hex, 0x0A, or equivalent to `"\x0A"`. `"\xA0"` is the representation of 0xA0, which is not a valid character. When you use `h` and `H` unpack methods then `A` is interpreted as a hex digit A, not as the value 0x41. In any case, `h` and `H` don't seem to be very useful in my limited testing.

Comment: One last question. How is `1000` translating into `A` or even 0. Similarly how `0010` transalated into `A` or 0.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: It's all about notation: `0b1000` (binary) is `0x8` (hex) or `8` (decimal). Methods like `pack` and `unpack` will convert between those if you like. You can also do conversion with `to_s` and `to_i` like `'0a'.to_s(16)` which returns `10`, or `10.to_s(16)` which returns `'a'` since `16` is the base argument, which could be anything you want, like 2 (binary), 8 (octal), 16 (hex), or anything else you want: `(6 * 9).to_s(13)` gives `42`.

Comment: `0b1000` is same as `0x8`. And `0b0010` is same as `0x2`. How did that translate into `A` and `0`?

Comment: Not sure where you're seeing those translations. Remember it's not `A` the character being converted, but `A` the hex digit. `['b'].pack('h')` is the same as `['B'].pack('h')` even though ASCII-wise they are different.

Comment: But `A` the hex digit is same as `1010` in binary. I do not see `1010` binary value. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you do: `['a'].pack('h').ord.to_s(2)` is `"1010"`